# How to configure multiple service tasks (for custom workitem handlers) inside a single process in bpmn (jbpm6)

Tags: java, jbpm, bpmn

I am new to jbpm6. I was able to configure and run a single service task with Custom workitem handler.
However, when i try to configure multiple service tasks within a single process, it doesn't work.
Can somebody please help? Thanks in advance !

Below is my working code for a single service task.

```
    <itemDefinition id="_sItem" structureRef="String" />
    <itemDefinition id="_2_InMessageType" structureRef="java.lang.String" />
    <message id="_2_InMessage" itemRef="_2_InMessageType" />

    <interface id="_handlingServiceInterface" name="myService">
        <operation id="_handlingServiceOperation" name="">
            <inMessageRef>_2_InMessage</inMessageRef>
        </operation>
    </interface>

    <process id="SingleNode_Process" isExecutable="true"
        processType="Private" name="Service Process">
        <property id="s" itemSubjectRef="_2_InMessageType" />

        <startEvent id="start-state" name="Start" />

        <serviceTask id="node" name="myservice" implementation="Other"
            operationRef="_handlingServiceOperation">
        </serviceTask>

   <endEvent id="end-state" name="End">
            <terminateEventDefinition />
        </endEvent>

    <sequenceFlow id="flow_N1000C" sourceRef="start-state"
            targetRef="node" />
   <sequenceFlow id="flow_N10017" sourceRef="node"
            targetRef="end-state" />

    </process>




ProcessInstance processInstance = null;
        KieHelper kieHelper = new KieHelper();

        KieBase kbase = kieHelper.addResource(ResourceFactory
                    .newClassPathResource("test.bpmn"))
                    .build();

        KieSession ksession = kbase.newKieSession();

        try{
            ksession.getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler("Service Task",  new MyTaskHandler());
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
                System.err.println("WorkitemHandler==>"+ex.toString());
        }


        try{
            processInstance = ksession.startProcess("SingleNode_Process");
        }

        catch(WorkflowRuntimeException e){
            System.err.println("processInstance Exception ==>"+e.toString());

        }

        ksession.dispose();
```

I would like to have multiple servicetask pointing to different Custom WorkItemHandlers, above.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you overrode the "Service Task" node. What you need to do is write a separate work item handler.  The documentaion is [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/jBPMDomainSpecificProcesses.html)

Basic steps are:

1. Create a work item definition [work item definition - wid](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/jBPMDomainSpecificProcesses.html#d0e13570)
2. Create the java work item handler [handler class](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/jBPMDomainSpecificProcesses.html#sec.example.notifications.workitemhandler)
3. Drag and drop wid onto bpmn
4. Register handler (similar to what you did for "Service Task Above"), use
   string you used in wid definition:   [ "name" : "